# Why was the global 'angular' variable removed from angularjs.TypeScript.DefinitelyTyped?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, typescript

Upgrading from [angularjs.TypeScript.DefinitelyTyped](https://github.com/borisyankov/DefinitelyTyped/blob/master/angularjs/angular.d.ts) 2.1.6 to 3.1.2 removed accessibility of the static `angular` variable I was using for module declaration files.

The following now gets an error that the symbol `angular` cannot be properly resolved.

```
angular
    .module("someModule")....
```

Resharper provides an option to import the variable from an external module, but this does not work.

Was the exposure of a global `angular` variable in earlier versions an error? Was it not intended to be used in the way my project has used it?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

It's a bug with Resharper 9.0. The fix is scheduled for the 9.1 release. You can do one of two things to remedy it now:

1. Disable Resharper by going to  Tools->Options->Resharper-> Suspend. Note that you'll lose all Resharper features and you'll probably want to re-enable VS's Intellisense.
2. Get the latest [9.1 EAP release](https://confluence.jetbrains.com/display/ReSharper/ReSharper+9.1+EAP) if you're comfortable to pre-release versions.

Comment: Thanks! Tools->Options->Resharper-> Suspend also works and you don't have to restart VS. Now time to post an issue with JetBrains :).

Comment: https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/RSRP-431238 Bug issue opened. Vote it up if this impacts you.

Comment: To turn off resharper inspections just for typescript: Resharper->Options->Code Inspection->Settings->Skipped elements->File masks to skip: *.ts.

Answer (score 2):

I still see it in there. I suppose it's because the new version of the file uses syntax that is new to TypeScript 1.4. Either upgrade your compiler or downgrade to an earlier version of the .d.ts file.

Comment: It was Resharper in my situation.Disabling it and it behaves as you are reporting.